# Geoplot multiple addresses from XML in R

Tags: xml, r, geocoding

I am trying to accumulate addresses for the purpose of plotting them on a map in R.  I am acquiring the addresses manually and entering them into a .csv to import into R.  The format of the .csv is as follows:

> streetnumber  |  street  | city  |  state
>
> 1150  | FM 1960 West Road  | Houston  | TX
>
> 701 | Keller Parkway |  Keller  | TX

Each heading (streetnumber, street, city, & state) is for a unique column and the data beneath are separated into their respective column.

I have R reading the information from the .csv and transforming it into the proper format for use with the Google Maps API.  I have the API produce an .xml file with the information corresponding to the address entered.  A minimal working example follows:

```
streetnumber1<-paste(data$streetnumber,sep="")
street1<-gsub(" ","+",data$street)
street2<-paste(street1,sep="")
city1<-paste(data$city,sep="")
state1<-paste(data$state,sep="")

url<-paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="
,streetnumber1,"+",street2,",+",city1,",+",state1,"&sensor=false",sep="")
```

Calling `url` produces two web addresses that can be entered into a web browser to navigate to the .xml data provided by the Google Maps API.

I would like for this to occur for all of the addresses in the .csv file, without my declaring how many times the url should be generated.  I feel this is the job for an `apply` function, but I'm uncertain how to go about it.  Once I automate the interaction between R and the API, I would like to parse the obtained .xml so that I can extract the information I'm seeking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me from this question what exactly you are trying to get from Google. I **assume** it's the latitude and longitude. If it is, try something like the code following the screenshot. EDIT: revised to include alternative (and simpler) approach using `geocode` function from `ggmap` package as per Ari B. Friedman's comment.

[image: screenshot]

```
# Read in the text from your example
mydf <- read.csv(con <- textConnection(
    "streetnumber|street|city|state
    1150|FM 1960 West Road|Houston|TX
    701|Keller Parkway|Keller|TX"), header = TRUE, sep = "|", check.names = FALSE)

# APPROACH 1 - works but Approach 2 probably better (see below)
# Create a new column for the URL to pass to Google API
mydf$url <- with(mydf, paste("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=",
                             streetnumber,
                             gsub(" ", "+", street),
                             city, "+",
                             state, "+",
                             "&sensor=false",
                             sep = ""))

# Check to see what we have in the data frame
str(mydf)

library(XML)
latlon <- lapply(mydf$url, function(x) { # process each element in the column 'url'
       myxml <- xmlTreeParse(x, useInternal = TRUE) # pass the element (an URL) to the XML function
       # parse the result
       lat = xpathApply(myxml, '/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat', xmlValue)[[1]]
       lon = xpathApply(myxml, '/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng', xmlValue)[[1]]
       data.frame(lat = lat, lon = lon) # return the latitude and longitude as a data frame
   })

# We end up with a list of data frames, so merge the data frames into one:
library(reshape)
latlon <- merge_all(latlon)

# Then bolt the columns on to your existing data frame
mydf <- cbind(mydf, latlon, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# We want the latitude and longitude to numbers, not characters
mydf$lat <- as.numeric(mydf$lat)
mydf$lon <- as.numeric(mydf$lon)

require(ggmap)

# APPROACH 2 - let ggmap do the heavy lifting (and 
# comment out Approach 1 if you use this)

mydf$location <- with(mydf, paste(streetnumber,street, city, state,sep = ", "))

latlon <- geocode(mydf$location)
mydf <- cbind(mydf, latlon, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Now plot.
# Be careful when specifying the zoom argument, because larger values can cause
# points to be dropped by geom_point()
ggmap(get_googlemap(maptype = 'roadmap', zoom = 6, scale = 2), extent = 'panel') +
       geom_point(data = mydf, aes(x = lon, y = lat), fill = "red", colour = "black",
                  size = 3, shape = 21)
```

Answer (score 6):

The [`ggmap`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/ggmap.pdf) package has a `geocode` function which I'd highly recommend using rather than reinventing the wheel here.

Edit: Since you say "multiple addresses," you may prefer [my version](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo/blob/master/R/Contributed.R#L4) which has a `data.frame` method and some robustness checks built in for batch geocoding, and allows the use of Bing Maps API (with 25K per day limits instead of 2.5K per day like Google Maps).

Comment: +1 for significantly simplifying the whole thing - had not used this before.

Comment: Just figured I'd spare someone else the trouble...I [wrote my own](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo/blob/master/R/Contributed.R#L4) before discovering `ggmaps`.  Now we're trying to incorporate the non-overlapping functionality (especially Bing Maps API interfacing) into the `ggmaps` version.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I have run into the 2.5k limit on Google before so the 25k quota on Bing sounds interesing. Does Bing seem to be equally useful/accurate?

Comment: @SlowLearner It does.  Also seems to have less of a rate limit than Google, which is helpful when batching things.

Answer (score 1):

When you use google Mpas API , it is better to use his JSON API.  XML it is not as lightweight as JSON.

For continuity, I slightly modify your origin code and I use `RJSONIO` package.

```
## I read your data
dat <- read.table(text = '
streetnumber | street | city | state
1150 | FM 1960 West Road | Houston | TX
701 | Keller Parkway | Keller | TX',header= T, sep = '|')

library(RJSONIO)
## here the use of json in placee of xml
## the static part of the url request
url.base <- "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="

## I create a data.frame with your formatted data
dat2 <- data.frame(
  streetnumber1 = paste(dat$streetnumber,sep=""),
  street2 = paste(gsub(" ","+",dat$street),sep=""),
  city1 = paste(dat$city,sep=""),
  state1 = paste(dat$state,sep=""))

## I use apply here to call it for each row
apply(dat2,1, function(x){
  url<-paste(url.base,x[1],"+",x[2],
             ",+",x[3],",+",x[4],"&sensor=false",sep="")
  res <- fromJSON(url)    ## single statement 
  ## e. to get lat/long
  lat.long <- res$results[[1]]$geometry$bounds$northeast
})
```

`res` here is just a list. You can subest and parse it easily.